# Error Firebase Database paths must not contain

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Necesito que me ayuden con lo siguiente, al parecer el `Firebase` me suelta un error con los puntos comas y otros.

Este es mi código :

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
    if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getUsuario()).exists()){
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "El Usuario ya existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }else{
        if(dataSnapshot.child(user.getEmail()).exists()){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "El Correo ya existe!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }else {
            usuarios.child(user.getUsuario()).setValue(user);
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,"Registrado!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
```

Este es el log :

> com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Invalid Firebase Database path: goldingui13@gmail.com. Firebase Database paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbtf.zzjl(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference.child(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.child(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.example.gianp.demo.MainActivity$2$1.onDataChange(MainActivity.java:72)
>                                                        at com.google.firebase.database.Query$1.onDataChange(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbpx.zza(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbqx.zzZS(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbra$1.run(Unknown Source)
>                                                        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)

Comment: el código que incluyes no tiene nada que ver con el error.  Relee la explicación en la respuesta de @jorgesys que ahí está la solución bien clara

Answer (score 1):

El problema es:

> Invalid Firebase path: .com. Firebase paths must not contain '.', '#', '$', '[', or ']'

La nomenclatura de la ruta donde se encuentra la base de datos no puede tener los siguientes caracteres: `'.', '#', '$', '[', o ']'`
Estas asignando como ruta donde se localiza la base de datos un email, lo cual es incorrecto:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La referencia es incorrecta, no debes usar los caracteres antes mencionados:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://<......>.firebaseio.com/");
```

Puedes usar este nombre, eliminando el  "." y "@" :

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference("https://gianprphotmailcom.firebaseio.com/");
```

o s**implemente obtener la referencia de esta forma, es lo más adecuado ya que toma el url que definiste cuando configuraste tu proyecto**:

```
DatabaseReference reference = database.getReference();
```

Comment: No entendi tu explicacion, solo quiero solucionarlo porque necesito que a la hora de registrarse tampoco el email sea repetido

Comment: @GianPaulRamírezPacheco agrega toda tu clase el código que presentas no es importante.